# PHP - is it possible to instantiate too many objects

Tags: php

I have PHP program that requires me to instantiate 1800 objects, and each object is associated with 7-10 arrays filled with historical data (about 500 records per array).This program is run by cron every 5 minutes, and not by users.

Anyways, the designer of the program says instantiating 1800 objects at once is required, and is not something we can change. My question is whether or not instantiating this many objects alone is a "code smell", and if having this much data in memory (arrays consisting of a total of 9,000,000 records), is something that would be hard for PHP to handle (assuming adequate memory is available on the host).

Thanks

Comment: Short answer: not necessarily. I would question whether PHP is the right tool for this job, perhaps.

Comment: It all depends. Basically, the answer is no: as long as you have enough RAM, you can create instances. This question has a whiff of X-Y to it, though, perhaps post the code in question on codereview, because I think it's more than likely that you can do the same thing without having to create those 1800 instances all at once

Comment: 1800 is a pretty small number for a computer. 1800 objects can be created and torn down in a matter of milliseconds, repeatedly. The question is: is it *too slow* or resource intensive? Does anyone really care about the number of objects except you? Does writing it this way in OO make it more maintainable and is that a significant benefit over writing it any other way?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem agree but like i said below - 5mins cron to have 1800 object on top of his webapp i would go wary even if memory sufficient right? A fine tune code + fine tune DB he would avoid this  memory issue by far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes and objects are mostly a conceptual tool used to organise code in a logical fashion that more or less applies to "things" in the real world. There's no significant difference for the computer when executing code written procedurally vs. object oriented code. The OO code may add a little bit of overhead compared to code written in the most optimal procedural way, but you will hardly ever notice this difference. 1800 objects can be created and destroyed within milliseconds, repeatedly. They by themselves are not a problem.

The question is: does writing it this way in OO significantly help code organisation? If done properly, likely yes. Is there any other realistic way to write the same algorithm in a procedural way which is *significantly* faster in execution? Would this other way be as logically structured, understandable and maintainable? Would the difference in code level quality be worth the difference in performance? Is it *really too slow* with its 1800 objects? Are the objects the bottleneck (likely: no) or is the overall algorithm and approach the bottleneck?

In other words: there's no reason to worry about 1800 objects unless you have a clear indication that they are a bottleneck, which they likely are not in and of themselves. Storing the same data in memory without an object wrapper will not typically significantly reduce any resource usage.

Comment: Perhaps drifting away from the OP's question, but 1800 objects isn't really an issue. Every day people post code here where they `$pdo->prepare('select * from tbl')->execute()->fetchAll()`, which basically does the same thing. the real bottleneck is often: inefficient computation, circular referencing of these objects or simply the DB connection being on another server, or using `localhost`, requiring a DNS lookup (comment just for completeness' sake). Oh and +1 for the effort

Comment: You're right, the bottle neck was the DB, not the objects. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

It would be slow as an application to initialize all those objects for your system to run. Now I know why you would do it as I have done it before - i would load a lookup object to avoid tapping into the DB if I'm going to do a look up.

However 1800 objects with a 500 record per array - that's pretty heavy and defeats the purpose of touching a database. Im aware that memory shall be available but considering that this is a load up without the crunch - I'm unsure that the 5mins cron will finish.

I suggest to benchmark this with a profiler to see what is the memory used and the time elapse before running this.

Comment: "Slow" is pretty relative. The question is: is there another way? And even if there is, is it *too slow* and would the other way be as maintainable and readable as the OO way?

Comment: @deceze considering its a cron, slow would be anything that goes towards the next mark of the next run of the cron right? Also OO is out of the picture here because he is asking more about performance than coding style. (I can smell terrible because of 1800 obj open already)

Comment: @azngunit81: creating 1800 objects won't take anything _near_ 5 minutes, heck, it takes a lot longer to blink! `$start = microtime(true);
$objs = array();
for ($i=0;$i<1800;++$i)
 $objs[] = new stdClass;
echo 'Time taken: ', microtime(true) - $start;` ==> ***Time taken: 0.001554012298584***... that's _less_ than 2ms

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem no but its filling up the array in memory too. building something empty of course is fast its about the equivalent of just incrementing a for loop.

Comment: @azngunit81: Add some computation, a custom class, and assign an array as property to each instance of 500 elements, and you still end up with less than a second needed to create 1800 instances [as seen here](https://ideone.com/vLuID9). 1800 objects is not likely to be the bottleneck, no matter how you look at it. No matter how much memory is used, as long as it's within the predefined limits, there shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a (practically relevant) limit for the amount of objects itself. As long as there is enough physical RAM, you can always increase the [memory llimit](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit). However, from an architectural standpoint it might be very unwise to keep all of this in RAM for the whole execution time, when it is actually not needed. Because of their high dynamics PHP arrays are quite expansive, so it could be a massive performance hit. However, without any details or profiling it is not possible to give you a definitive answer.

But admittedly, it seems quite odd that so many objects are needed. A DBMS might be an alternative for handling this amount of data.

Comment: Depending on the complexity of the data and what needs to be done with it, having those objects in memory may be the most straight forward thing to do. An object by itself is not really all that heavy, not even 1800 of them.

Comment: Yeah sure, it just _seems_ odd that so many objects of the same type are needed. Without any more information, it might be a good idea to use a DBMS, because they are optimized for these kind of things.

Comment: @deceze agree - you can have a look up array loaded in memory rather than pinging the DB and doing joins. If you preload your data inside arrays and then crunch your data - it will be easier and lesss intensive since you wont need to run multiple queries to retrieve the simpler task.